# Parametros 'source' y 'data' en https://api.whatsapp.com

Tags: html, whatsapp

Estoy tratando de usar api de whatsapp web en mi proyecto, con lo cual pretendo tener una comunicación mediante un canal más amigable y común para los clientes. Es muy simple y sencillo su uso que es exactamente lo que ocupo en está ocasión.

Un ejemplo de como uso la api seria `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5211234567890&text=Me%20gustar%C3%ADa%20saber%20el%20precio%20del%20coche&source=&data=` dentro de la liga puedo especificar el número usando `phone=` y el mensaje con `text=` pero noto que puedo hacer uso de dos parámetros más, los cuales son `source=` y `data=` sin embargo no sé que puedo mandar mediante estos y no encuentro ejemplos o explicaciónes sobre estos dos parámetros. **¿Alguien sabe algo sobre esto?** cualquier información al respecto sería de mucha ayuda.

De ante mano, gracias.

Comment: no tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta... Mas bien ya estoy cansado de buscar en la web la respuesta a estos dos parametros y nada. Espero que con esta nueva respuesta alguien nos ayude.

Comment: Simple, en `source` se envian, imagenes-videos-audios y en `data` se envia la informacion que tienes en tu propia base de datos, como ID_usuario, id_mensaje, _token entre algunas cosas